# How to remove computedFn invoked outside reactive context warning

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I can not avoid to sometimes call `mobx.computedFn` functions inside asyncronous callbacks. This fills the console with warnings I would like to remove:

```
invoking a computedFn from outside an reactive context won't be memoized, unless keepAlive is set
```

There was a configuration option `warnOnUnsafeComputationReads` in MobX 4 (https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/961), but the flag is not working and I can not see it in the docs either. Has it been deprecated? I could not find any more references to it.

> Mobx 4 will introduce mobx.configure({ warnOnUnsafeComputationReads: true })

There is the option to add the `keepAlive` flag [https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html#options-for-computed](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils#keepalive) to every `computedFn` affected, but it is something I do not want to do just to avoid a warning. Using the flag have its downsides and may introduce memory leaks and in many cases the computation is trivial and does not benefit from the catching.

> keepAlive: don't suspend this computed value if it is not observed by anybody. Be aware, this can easily lead to memory leaks as it will result in every observable used by this computed value, keeping the computed value in memory!

**Question**

How can I make the call to `computefFn` methods inside async callbacks to not trigger the MobX warning? Is there a way to do this on a case by case basis, so every warning can be evaluated to decide if it can be hidden or not?

or much better

How can I write the call to `computefFn` methods inside async callbacks to be considered being in a reactive context?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the asynchronous code via `runInAction` utility function?

Try wrapping the `computedFn` call inside the `runInAction`.

https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html

Comment: A `computedFn` is not an action. Why wrap it in `runInAction`?.  The link addresses working with `mobx.actions` in asyncronous code, but gives no hint about ` computed` values.